# Are there email services that provide the possibility to create a discussion list?

Tags: email, mailing-list

I discovered recently, that professional discussion lists usually integrate software like "majordomo". However, this looks a little outside my current skills :) and I may integrate it in the future.

Right now, I would just need - for example - to make an email address in which to store emails, and use it as a discussion list (so that any email directed to this account will be automatically redirected to an address list associated with it). Is there any email service out there through which I can easily obtain something similar?

Best
Luca

Comment: That might depend on what capabilities you want, how many people you'd be sending to, how often, and how much are you willing to pay.

Comment: Have you considered [searching google for "public discussion list services"](https://www.google.com/search?q=public+discussion+list+services)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a list of that sort that's hosted at [SimpleLists](https://www.simplelists.com/). I'm not the administrator of the list, so I don't know all of the capabilities, but at the very least I know that it supports an archive, a digest mode as well as a reflector mode, and lists can have around 400 members. Some features may require payment.